# In Laravel Eloquent inserts an empty record to table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the class `Word` that extends Eloquent. I have added two records manually, and they are fetching fine with `Word::all()` method. But when I'm trying to create new object and save it, Eloquent inserts empty values into table.

So, here is the model

```
class Word extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'words';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public $word;
    public $senseRank = 1;
    public $partOfSpeech = "other";
    public $language;
    public $prefix;
    public $postfix;
    public $transcription;
    public $isPublic = true;
}
```

Here is the database migration script

```
     Schema::create('words', function($table) {
         $table->increments('id');
         $table->string('word', 50);
         $table->tinyInteger('senseRank');
         $table->string('partOfSpeech', 10);
         $table->string('language', 5);
         $table->string('prefix', 20)->nullable();
         $table->string('postfix', 20)->nullable();
         $table->string('transcription', 70)->nullable();
         $table->boolean('isPublic');
     });
```

And here is the code I'm trying to run

```
Route::get('create', function()
{
    $n = new Word;
    $n->word         = "hello";
    $n->language     = "en";
    $n->senseRank    = 1;
    $n->partOfSpeech = "other";
    $n->save();
});
```

And all I get is a new record with correct new id, but all the other fields are empty strings or zeros. How could it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove all properties from your model because now Eloquent won't work as it should, your class should look like this:

```
class Word extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'words';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

If you need default values for some fields, you could add them for example when creating table using `default`, for example:

```
$table->tinyInteger('senseRank')->default(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Comment out / get rid of class fields you are setting:

```
// public $word;
// public $senseRank = 1;
// public $partOfSpeech = "other";
// public $language;
```

Laravel uses magic `__get()` and `__set()` methods to store fields internally. When you have fields defined, this does not work.

You can use model events to set defaults, add this method to you model:

```
public static function boot() {
    parent::boot();
    static::creating(function($object) {
        $object->senseRank = 1;
        $object->partOfSpeech = "other";
    });
}
```